# I'd like my navigation bar to be centered, but nothing I do seems to impact it whatsoever

Tags: css, html

The link to my testing page—where my testing of centering the nav-ul-li bar is taking place—is as follows: http://bramh.coornhert.website/startpagina.html

the code is as follows:

```css
header {
color: GhostWhite;
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: courier new;
}
body {background-image: url("images/wallpapermain.jpg");
color: white;
} 
p { border-width: 3px;
   border-style: groove;
   border-color: light-blue;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   height: 1200px;
   width: 1000px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "verdana";
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-top: 50px;
}

img {border-radius:10px;
}
a:link.img { color:#007DC5;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
a:visited.img { color:#007DC5;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
} 
a:hover.img { color: red;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}
/* menu */
a:link,a:visited {
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
background-color: black;
border: 2px #033 ridge;
border-radius: 10px; 
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,a:active {
background-color: dark-grey; 
color: orange;
width: 140px;
}
nav {
width: 800px;
height: 30px;
padding-top: 0px; 
}
ul {
margin:0;
position: fixed;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
nav{
text-attachment: fixed;
}
a.huidig_blauw {
background-color: white;
color: black;
}
a.huidig_rood {
background-color: green;
color: black;
width: auto;
}
a.tweede_menu {
background-color: red;
color: blue;
width: auto;
}
/* CSS Document */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Website Bram</title>
    <link href="shoop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>Bram Heesen</header> 
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="huidig_blauw" href="startpagina.html">HOME</a>
                <a class="huidig_rood" href="paginainformatica.html">Pagina Informatica</a>
                <a class="huidig_rood" href="paginamijzelf.html">Over Mij</a>
                <a class="huidig_rood" href="paginakeuzeonderwerp.html">PaginaKeuzeonderwerp</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>
        <br><br>
     <audio controls="controls"autoplay="autoplay">
            <source src="music/chiptune.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
            <source src="music/chiptune.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            Sorry, je internetprogramma kan deze muziek niet laten horen.
        </audio>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your code for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

In the future you should provide your code directly in your post so that if someone stumbles upon your question at a later date, they can see the issue. If you link to your site and then fix your issue on the site, or the site is no longer up, the link becomes irrelevant to the question.

That said, you can center your menu elements by removing the `float:left;` and adding `text-align:center;` to the `ul`.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Welcome to SO!

*UPDATE USING OP's CODE*

```css
header {
color: GhostWhite;
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: courier new;
}
body {background-image: url("images/wallpapermain.jpg");
color: white;
} 
p { border-width: 3px;
   border-style: groove;
   border-color: light-blue;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   height: 1200px;
   width: 1000px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "verdana";
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-top: 50px;
}

img {border-radius:10px;
}
a:link.img { color:#007DC5;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
a:visited.img { color:#007DC5;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
} 
a:hover.img { color: red;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}
/* menu */
a:link,a:visited {
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
background-color: black;
border: 2px #033 ridge;
border-radius: 10px; 
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,a:active {
background-color: dark-grey; 
color: orange;
width: 140px;
}
nav {
height: 30px;
padding-top: 0px; 
}
ul {
margin:0;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
nav{
text-attachment: fixed;
}
a.huidig_blauw {
background-color: white;
color: black;
}
a.huidig_rood {
background-color: green;
color: black;
width: auto;
}
a.tweede_menu {
background-color: red;
color: blue;
width: auto;
}
/* CSS Document */
```

```html
<header>Bram Heesen</header> 
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
<a class="huidig_blauw" href="startpagina.html">HOME</a>
<a class="huidig_rood" href="paginainformatica.html">Pagina Informatica</a>
<a class="huidig_rood" href="paginamijzelf.html">Over Mij</a>
<a class="huidig_rood" href="paginakeuzeonderwerp.html">PaginaKeuzeonderwerp</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<p>
<br><br>
<audio controls="controls"autoplay="autoplay" >
<source src="music/chiptune.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="music/chiptune.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Sorry, je internetprogramma kan deze muziek niet laten horen.
</audio>

</p>
```

Comment: Ah ok I see, other places preferred links so that's why I did it this way, but I'll keep that in mind. Even with the newly added code it's not working, I shall post all of the code here again in a new comment.

Comment: Remove the `width` from your `nav` and remove `position:fixed;` from your `ul`. See updated answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference, any other ideas?

Comment: You can see in my code snippet that the menu is centered, what else are you wanting to do?

Comment: I'd like a menu in which people can leave messages, which will be sent to my E-mailaddress, but it doesn't work. Do I need to create a new post for that?